# Map shows default marker but it is never set

Tags: android, dictionary, marker

[map with default marker that is never set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41szV.png)

In the middle of the map there is a marker, which is always shown on this location when I start the activity with the map fragment in it. But I never set this marker... Does someone know why this is and maybe how I can delete this marker?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    if(permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        getCurrentLocation();
        onSearch();
    }else if(permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
        onSearch();
    }
}
//gets current location of the user.
public void getCurrentLocation() {
    double lat = 0;
    double lng = 0;
    try {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); //allows query of current location.
    }catch(SecurityException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Geocoder geocoderGetAddress = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
    try{
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if(location!=null) {
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lng = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }catch(SecurityException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //the rest of this method gets the address from the geocoder, so that it can be displayed as a String on the marker info window.
    String displayAddress ="";
    try {
        List<Address> currAddress = geocoderGetAddress.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        if(currAddress.size() >0){
            for(int i=0; i<currAddress.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++){
                displayAddress += currAddress.get(0).getAddressLine(i) +"\n";
            }
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,lng)).title(myLoc).snippet(displayAddress));
    LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myLatLng));
    initAcceptButton();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are adding it with `mMap.addMarker` and animating it to the center with `mMap.animateCamera`

Comment: No, I'm only adding this marker, when I get the current location of the smartphone.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that that is where you are adding it, your current lat/lng just hasn't been fixed yet.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem with adding

```
if(lat!= 0 || lng != 0){
//add marker here
}
```